# What does this mean in Mozilla: "let blocks and let expressions are obsolete"

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, spidermonkey

I bumped into a few statements from people that "let blocks and let expressions are obsolete" in SpiderMonkey, while there's very little information about it. I'm wondering what does this exactly mean? Isn't the "let" statement a popular new feature in ES6?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1023609

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: `let` variable declarations are fine. And they are the reason why "let blocks" are obsolete.

Comment: @Bergi Could you please give some examples? I don't understand what "let blocks" or "let expressions" exactly means.

Comment: @XunYang: And you probably don't have to. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nooooo you are making me really curious here

Answer (score 6):

`let` variable declaration are still widely used. Something like:

```
let i = 4;
```

Is perfectly fine. The article you linked talks about let *blocks*. Something like

```
let (x = x + 1, y = x - 1) {
  console.log("This is a let block!");
}
```

Is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: I head no idea that even was a thing. Good to know I can forget this.

Comment: Thank you! This is really interesting :)

Answer (score 5):

[JS1.7 (from 2006)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160728221242/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) introduced features like destructuring and `let`, however they were different from `let` and destructuring that we know from ES6. The old implementation is obsolete, and no longer supported by Firefox' engine since v41.

You can read more about [`let` blocks](http://web.archive.org/web/20160829133806/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_blocks) and [`let` expressions](http://web.archive.org/web/20160829133806/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_expressions) in an old revision of MDN's page on the `let` keyword.